# Can I execute LOAD DATA INFILE from MySQL in Kettle Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, kettle

I'm building a Kettle transformation for ETL a large text file, the transformation it's ok, but the process to load is pretty slow, I know that Kettle have a function named MySQL Bulk Loader but  only works in Linux and I'm working on Windows enviroment.

I want to use LOAD DATA INFILE from MySQL after the transformation, I try to  use an Execute Sql Script, but launch a "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error, directly in MySQL the script execute pretty well.

Somebody know if I can use LOAD DATA INFILE in Kettle or have some better idea for load a large text file in MySQL from Kettle

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use kettle job to deliver file to MySQL server (or on other MySQL mchine, where the mysql client is running) and from the system call script execution for loading file:

> mysql -u user -ppassword test_db < import_data.sql